# Can't resignFirstResponder with UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I have a `UITextView`. I implemented a navigationBar `UIBarButtonItem` to respond to a touch and resign the firstResponder for my `UITextView`.

But, when the selector method is called, the keyboard doesn't get dismissed. I checked the UITextView's responder status with `isFirstResponder` and it returns YES. I also checked it with `canResignFirstResponder` and the return value is NO.

I must be missing something here...why is it returning NO?

I get that I can override `canResignFirstResponder` by subclassing UITextView, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Here's a code snippet:

```
- (void) commentCancelButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Cancel button touched");
    [self.navigationBar popNavigationItemAnimated: NO];

    if ([self.textInput.textView canResignFirstResponder] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"I don't want to resign!");
    }

    [self.textInput.textView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: What is `self.textInput`'s class?

Comment: It's a custom class that subclasses `UIView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I had a 'UITextViewDelegate' method in my 'textInput' view, `textViewShouldEndEditing` that was overrided to return `NO`. Changed it to `YES` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone wants to hide the keyboard when you touch outside of the textview, it's pretty easy...

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    [self.xFront resignFirstResponder];
}
```

xFront is my outlet to my `UITextView`.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing your UITextField by way of a UIView subclass is a little non-standard. If I were you I'd get myself a direct handle on that UITextField right from inside your view controller. Set it up as a synthesized property of your view controller, give it the keyword IBOutlet so you can talk about it in Interface Builder, then make sure the outlet is hooked up to the text field.

In other words, rather than talking about `self.textInput.textView`, you want to be talking about `self.textView` directly. And double-check your IB outlet hookup, because I suspect that's where the real trouble is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though I'm not using Interface Builder for the view, it's done programatically.

Comment: Gotcha. Even more so, then, having a layer of abstraction between your controller and your UITextField is probably not a great idea.

Comment: Figured it out. I had a `UITextViewDelegate` method in my `textInput` view, `textViewShouldEndEditing` that was overrided to return NO. Changed it to YES and it solved the problem. Gah! But still, thank you for the advice.